# SQLite object from s3 to tables in memory with Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using Boto3 with python to retrieve Sqlite files from s3. Ultimately I need to write the data to an RDS database. The problem is that there are several version of the data stored in these objects so the data needs to be "munged" before writing out.

For security purposes I would like to avoid the intermediary step of storing the data in a file and then loading it from there.

Luckily the files are very small. They each consist of two tables and those two tables contain no more than five fields with one row.

To fetch the object I create an s3 client and do:

```
current_object = s3.get_object(**kwargs)
data = current_object["Body"]

for raw_file in data:
```

Then I have a bytes object that looks like:

```
raw_file = b'SQLite format 3\x00\x10\x00\x01\x01\x00@ yada, yada, yada'
```

Is there a way that I can load that into memory for munging that out without actually writing it to a file?

Comment: This is not possible with the standard Python sqlite library.  You can either use apsw and a VFS, or write the data to a temp file to load it.